# Can't debug to Local machine or device in VS 2015

Tags: debugging, process, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I recently updated from the Visual Studio 2015 Community RC to the final release, to developp Windows 10 apps, and noticed that now, I am incapable of debugging my application. The drop down menu to launch the app on normaly either an emulator, the local machine, or a connected device, is only giving me the option to "Attach...". When I press on that, I am shown a window "Attach to process", which lists all current processes on the PC and tries to get me to launch the app on one.

I am very confused, and I guess that you could be confused too, so here are some screenshots (sorry if it's in French):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Validate this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899901/visual-studio-2015-has-no-debug-option-beyond-remote-machine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are building for ARM (see the center of the black box at the top of your screenshot) so can only run on an ARM device. Change the drop down to build x86 and you can run locally or to an emulator (the Windows Phone emulators are x86 not ARM).

Comment: I have x86 but I dont get the option for local machine.

Comment: had to change it on the solution as well as the project.