# Visual Studio 2015 has no debug option beyond Remote Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just recently installed Visual Studio 2015. I'm new to the program completely and I can't figure out my issue. First of all, I'm running it on Windows 7 through VMWare Fusion. I had no issues installing it. I created a simple app to test it out, but there is no option except for "Remote Machine" to debug. I'm not sure how to get "Local Machine" in there. Please let me know if I didn't give enough information. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

just check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx

Under **Requeriments** it says:

"Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either."

So the only way you have to debug your app is in your remote test machine.

Hope it helps.